# Why is label not showing up in eventhandler method?

Tags: java, user-interface, javafx, label

This here is the event handler for a button, which pauses the program for 1 second. Whenever I pause it, I want a window to show up, saying that the program has been paused for 1 second. I have added a label, but it does not show up. Why is that happening?

```
        public void handle(MouseEvent me) {
            try {

                Label label1 = new Label("Paused for one second.");
                label1.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
                label1.setVisible(true);
                Thread.sleep(1000);

            } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                Thread.currentThread().interrupt();

            }
        }
    });
```

P.S. When I click the button, the screen freezes for a second, so the eventhandler is working, but the label simply does not show up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just create a new Label. You don't add it to a node.
Add your label to some pane of your scene to be able to show it. 
Create your label out of the handle methode and just do the `setVisible(true)` on the handle method. (By default the visibility is set to true. so set it to false when you create your label)